# Retrieve a json field from mysql field with PDO

Tags: php, slim

I have a database where I store some data, and one field is a json string.

I insert an json in this field:

```
        $stmt->bindParam(":settings", json_encode($widget->settings));
```

Then when I try to retrieve the record I get my row with the settings column as string. I need my data to be json, so I should decode this field before output my records. If i go with:

```
        $app->response->setBody(json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
```

I get something like:

```
"name":"My Name","label":null,"row":null,"settings":"{\"site\":\"dfsdf\",\"action\":\"UrlInfo\"}"
```

with settings escaped. I should first decode settings and then encode again to output my results. How can I do to solve this?

UPDATE:

I retrieve my data using PDO, so I get an array:

```
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Before I save this I have:

```
"settings":{"site":"fff","action":"UrlInfo"}}
```

Comment: What is the value of the string before you save it in DB?

Comment: Before I have the same json string. I'm using angularjs as frontend, so I work mainly with javascript object

Comment: From your post I can conclude you are encoding your data twice. First time before you insert it in DB, and second time when you are reading it from DB. When you read your data from DB, you should preform json_decode(YOUR STRING FROM DB) because your data is already encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you retrieve the data, you should use `json_decode` to reverse the encoding that you did when you inserted it.

```
foreach ($data as &$row) { // Use reference so we can modify in place
    $row['settings'] = json_decode($row['settings']);
}
$app->response->setBody(json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
```

Comment: I'm using PDO. So when I retrieve record I get an array, json_decode is expecting a string. I have update my question.

Comment: Let's say we've multi columns one of them is JSON field, is there any way to get that field as an object without using for?

Comment: @siniradam `for` is for looping over the rows, not the columns. You access any particular column with `$row['columnname']`

Comment: @siniradam Maybe you're looking for something like `array_map('json_decode', array_column($data, 'settings'))`